# Can't see listing of files in my commit

Tags: macos, atlassian-sourcetree

For some reason, source tree does not show the listing of files in my commit.  I am on the "Workspace->History" view, It's set to "All Branches", "Show Remote Branches" and "Ancestral Order".

The tree shows up fine.
Under that, it shows me commit description, SHA1, parents, author, date, labels.  On the right, it shows me only the diff of only one of files in the commit.

If I drag up the lower border, I can see the Command History.
If I create and stage new files, I do see them appear in the lower portion of the view in "Staged files" and "Unstaged files", and I can click on each file, and the diff on the right shows the differences.  But once I commit, I can no longer see the file listing.

I know that all the files are committed as I see them in ls-files, it seems like I'm missing an option or preference somewhere in the tool.  Anyone know what I'm referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.  I did not realize there was a table with "Filename / Path" headers.  On a mac at least, you can resize the contents of the table to a 0 height, so that it completely disappears and there is no way to bring it back without hovering over with a mouse.